# Solve Esri Toolbox produces empty Shapefiles (make route layer)

Tags: arcpy, sql, network-analyst

I am making a Toolbox for finding the best Pizzaroute between 7 Pizzastops.

We used the `make.routelayer` from ArcPy. Our Pizzaroutetime expressed not our expression, rather all Firestations (station 1-49). Our Outputeroute shows a route between all Firestations.

How do we get the right output?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import time
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "d:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NetworkAnalyst\Tutorial\SanFrancisco.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("network")

NetzwerkWork = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
  if NetzwerkWork == '':
     NetzwerkWork = 'd:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NetworkAnalyst\Tutorial\SanFrancisco.gdb\FireStations.shp'
arcpy.env.workspace = NetzwerkWork

networkDataset = "d:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NetworkAnalyst\Tutorial\SanFrancisco.gdb\Transportation\Streets_ND"
stops = "d:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NetworkAnalyst\Tutorial\FireStations.shp"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
stops_select = "d:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NetworkAnalyst\Tutorial\SanFrancisco.gdb\Pizza_Time"
stops_select2 = "d:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NetworkAnalyst\Tutorial\SanFrancisco.gdb\Pizza_Distance"

Adress_locator = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

Punkt_1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

Punkt_2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

Punkt_3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

Punkt_4 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

Punkt_5 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)

Punkt_6 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)

Expression ="NAME = 'Station 1'" + " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Station 2'"+ " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Station 3'"+ " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Punkt_3'"+ " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Punkt_4'"+ " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Punkt_5'"+ " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Punkt_6'"
Pizza = arcpy.Select_analysis(stops, "Pizza_Time", Expression)
Pizzaroute_Time = arcpy.MakeRouteLayer_na(networkDataset, Pizza, "TravelTime", "USE_INPUT_ORDER", "PRESERVE_BOTH", "NO_TIMEWINDOWS", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "Oneway;RestrictedTurns", "USE_HIERARCHY", "", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "").getOutput(0)

Timeclass = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(Pizzaroute_Time)

TimeSublayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Pizzaroute_Time, Timeclass["Routes"])[0]

arcpy.na.AddLocations(Pizzaroute_Time, Timeclass["Stops"], stops)

arcpy.na.Solve(Pizzaroute_Time)

arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(TimeSublayer, "Pizza")

arcpy.AddMessage("Completed")
```

Additional information after receiving answer...

The SQL expression works fine.
Our Actually Expression looks like this:

```
Expression = "NAME = 'Station 1'" + " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Station 2'"+ " ""OR" +" " "NAME = 'Station 3'"
```

And we get an Output including only these 3 Points (Pizza_Time). 
Our Problem is that we can not do a route between these 3 Points from the Expression, Because the MakeRouteLayer Output ("Pizza") gives us a route between all the Points of the Input-Shapefile (FireStations).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit unclear. But the expression will not work when you name the variables `Punkt_6`, then use them like this `"NAME = 'Punkt_6'"`. `'Punkt_6'` with the quotes is just a string and not the value assigned to the variable.

Try using the IN operator instead of multiple OR, format and addfielddelimiters:

```
Expression = "{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=stops, field="NAME"), (Punkt_1, Punkt_2, ...))
```